# PRODUCTSUM per Group with IF Statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to be able to count Unique values, if some criteria are true and I am having a trouble.

Sample Date:

| Y/N | ID | WeekNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | AAA | 46 |
| True | BBB | 46 |
| False | CCC | 46 |
| False | AAA | 47 |
| True | BBB | 47 |
| False | BBB | 48 |

I need to Get the count of Unique IDs for each Weeknum, when True

So that I get this result:

| Week # | # of Unique True |
| --- | --- |
| Week 46 | 2 |
| Week 47 | 1 |
| Week 48 | 0 |

I hope I have described it well.

Answer (score 2):

Try: The formula shown below needs `LAMBDA()` helper function `MAP()` which helps in iterating each of the unique week# to get the corresponding unique ids counts.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a, C2:C7,
     b, B2:B7,
     c, A2:A7,
     ua, UNIQUE(a),
     HSTACK("Week "&ua, MAP(ua, LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(b,(c)*(x=a)))),0)))))
```

---

& without using `LAMBDA()` helper functions and using `MMULT()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, UNIQUE(A2:C7),
     φ, TAKE(α,,-1),
     δ, UNIQUE(φ),
     HSTACK("Week "&δ, MMULT(--(δ=TOROW(φ*TAKE(α,,1))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))^0)))
```

---

Update without using `LAMBDA()` or `MMULT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
="Week "&UNIQUE(C2:C7)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$7,($E2="Week "&$C$2:$C$7)*$A$2:$A$7))),0)
```

---

Both formulas needs to fill down!

---

And more generic formula to get distinct counts using `SUMPRODUCT()`

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((E2="Week "&$C$2:$C$7)/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7,$B$2:$B$7,$C$2:$C$7,$C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,TRUE)),0))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

In column `# of Unique True` place this formula and copy down

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,TRUE,$C$2:$C$7,"="&SUM(IFERROR(--TEXTSPLIT($D2," "),0)))
```

where D2 is the cell of `Week 46`, or

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,TRUE,$C$2:$C$7,"="&SUM(IFERROR(--TEXTSPLIT(OFFSET($A$1,ROW()-1,COLUMN()-2)," "),0)))
```

in this case the function automatically  define its location.

**ADDED:**

Create a table like this

B10: `=TRANSPOSE("Week "&UNIQUE(C2:C7))`

A11: `=UNIQUE(B2:B7)`

B11: `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"=TRUE",$B$2:$B$7,$A11,$C$2:$C$7,MID(B$10,6,LEN(B$10)-5))`

B11 copy for the whole table

#N/A is only because of the array formula of my excel.

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work.

If there are any Duplicate IDs it only counts True for the Week, but does not take into account the IDs at all.

Comment: @Libor Pls. have a look on the added workaround.

Comment: @Libor Below the rows and to the end of the columns you can add a SUM function for the results if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:

=`LET(y,A2:A7,w,C2:C7,c,VSTACK("Week "&UNIQUE(w)),HSTACK(c,COUNTIFS(w,RIGHT(c,2),y,"TRUE")))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see duplicates per WeekNum to begin with. If so, then try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:C7),GROUPBY("Week "&DROP(x,,2),--TAKE(x,,1),SUM,0,0))
```

Comment: Sorry this does not work for duplicates, only counts Trues for the Week

Comment: @LiborMorávek, thanks for the clarity. You may want to edit your sample data to reflect you actually have duplicates.

Comment: @LiborMorávek, edited to account for duplicates among week# and ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your replies, using Lambdas and Let is a little too complicated for me and the use case.

I was wondering if this could be used as a solution.

1. Concatenate True/False, ID and Week Number in a separate column
2. Count duplicates in this new column
3. Divide 1 by the number of duplicates in the column
4. SUMIFS the Duplicates if true and if the week is 46

Comment: See I have updated the formulas, if you had followed my solution, one who has given very beginning the correct answer than the rest of the answers by understanding it clearly, if simplified without `LAMBDA()` you could have resolved it easily see the updates.

Comment: Since this is not an answer, maybe it fits better if you merge it into your original question and remove the "answer".